# How do I get permissions to work on discord.py

Tags: python

I am currently making a discord.py bot, but whenever I try to make a command that you need the permission for, it doesn't work.
For an example here is my ban command:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member:discord.User=None, reason=None):
    if member == None or member == ctx.author:
        await ctx.channel.send("You must specify a user, and one that isn't you.")
        return
    if reason == None:
        reason = "*Reason is not specified.*"

    message = (f"You have been banned from **{ctx.guild.name}** for {reason}!")
    await member.send(message)
    await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} was banned!")
```

I've made sure I am the bot have the required permissions yet I still get this error:

```
 raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

I've tried lots and still haven't been able to get this to work, and its not only for this ban command, a 'setnick' command also has the same error.
Please help me figure out the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send("You do not have the permissions required for this command.")
    return
```

Comment: Done that, all it does it get rid of the error.

Comment: and send msg? that user cant run cmd

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:
It was because the bot role was lower than the Member role, therefore the bot cannot ban the member.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).